# grid scrolling by code in C#

Tags: c#, gridview, scroll, row

I want scroll gridview by code in C#. when I added a row,then gridview show the last row. I used this:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[1];
```

but does not work correctly.

Comment: Have you tried to Focus it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this solution and this works well as long as the AutoSizeRowsMode property is NOT set to DisplayedCells:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.count-1;
```